# Restricted or Reserved Ports on IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, port

I want to know that

What is the Default Port and How many Ports which are Restricted or Reserved and what are they.?
Can i deploy my asp.net site on any Port.?

I already did google but i don't want to know a proper answer for it.

I am using IIS 7.0 and ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1):

There are no restricted or reserved ports. You can configure IIS to listen on any available port. This being said there are some standard conventions that people respect, like port 80 and 443 is for HTTP, 25 for SMTP, ...

So as long as the port is available and there are no other processes listening on it, you can use it.

Comment: What is the Default Port of IIS.?

Comment: IIS supports different protocols: HTTP, FTP, ... So there's no such notion as *default port of IIS*. If you use the HTTP protocol then the default port is 80. I suppose that this is your case since you are asking about an ASP.NET application. On the other hand if your application needs to support SSL, then that would be a binding on the 443 port.